# Override backbone 'set' method

Tags: backbone.js

I want to override backbone set method so that whenever I set a value to backbone Model the callbacks registered on that attribute get called without checking for same previous value of that attribute .

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults : {
         prop1 : true 
     }
});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize : function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model,"change:prop1", this.callback);

     },
     callback : function(){
        // set is called on prop1
     }
});

var m1 = new model();
var v1 = new view({model:m1});
m1.set("prop1",true); // It doesn't trigger callback because I'm setting the same value to prop1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can write a new method in backbone model set like this :

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         prop1: true;
     },

     // Overriding set
     set: function(attributes, options) {
        // Will be triggered whenever set is called
        if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(prop1)) {
           this.trigger('change:prop1');
        }  

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
     }
});
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. See [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1391).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the signature of function `set` differs from the one depicted in the accepted answer.

```
export var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function (key, val, options) {
        // custom code
        var result = Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, key, val, options);
        // custom code
        return result;
    }
});
```

See:

- http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html
- https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1391