# Backbone Entity

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new in backbone. But when i study model entity I don't understand a few things. It would be great if we can define model property as in standard language like java or C#. Is it possible something like that. So my idea look like this:

```js
MyEntity = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // define class property here
    defaults: {
        name: null,
        surname: null
    }
});

var entity = new MyEntity();

//My Idea:
name = entity.get('name'); // return null
test = entity.get('test'); // this should throw exception, because test property does not exist
exist = entity.has('name'); // should return true. Property exist, but is empty
entity.set('test2', 'hello'); // this should threw exception, property test2 does not exist

// Reality:
name = entity.get('name'); // return null
test = entity.get('test'); // return undefined
exist = entity.has('name'); // return false
entity.set('test2', 'hello'); // ok, valid
```

So is it possible to modify backbone model to work like this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up your own custom getters and setters.

```
var MyEntity = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: null,
        surname: null
    },

    customHas: function (key) {
        return this.attributes.hasOwnProperty(key);
    },

    customGet: function (key) {
        if (this.customHas(key)) {
            return this.get(key);

        } else {
            throw('property does not exist');
        }
    },

    customSet: function (key, val) {
        if (this.customHas(key)) {
            this.set(key, val);

        } else {
            throw('property does not exist');
        }
    }
});
```

[See this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4keowx0z/).

Comment: Thank you Adam. But I like words 'get' ans 'set' :-) for getter and setter. So may i rewrite these methods? Thanks

Comment: If you really want to do that, [it's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922503/override-backbone-set-method), but more complicated. [Backbone uses "get", "set", and "has" internally](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) in a few different spots, so you'd have to redo a lot more of their methods with try/catches (`isNew()`, `where()`, and the `Model` constructor to name a few). Also, anyone else looking at your code and referring to Backbone documentation would get very confused!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a language feature but the way backbone is implemented. Basically, backbone is a backbone and not a framework, means, you can extend it and write your won logic on top of it.

It could be something like:

```js
var AbstractModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  get: function () {
    var value = Backbone.Model.get.apply(this, arguments);
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('undefined');
    }
    return value;
  },
  has: function (attr) {
    return typeof attr != 'undefined';
  }
});
```

If you want a more opinionated version of backbone, with schema validation, etc, take a look at [Ampersand.js](http://ampersandjs.com) or other frameworks such as [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would define a specific prototype with getters and setters, and only use the getters and setters to manipulate the instances.

```
var MyEntity = function(name, surname) {
    Backbone.Model.call(this);
    this.set({"name": name, "surname": surname});
};
MyEntity.prototype = Object.create(Backbone.Model.prototype);
MyEntity.prototype.constructor = MyEntity;
_.extend(MyEntity.prototype, {
    getName: function() {
        return this.get("name");
    },
    setName: function(name) {
        return this.set({"name":name});
    },
    getSurname: function() {
        return this.get("surname");
    },
    setSurname: function(name) {
        return this.set({"surname":name});
    }
});
```

If this is too much work for you, you can write a function that generates the prototype from a definition object, something like :

```
function generatePrototype(properties) {
    var module = function() {
        Backbone.Model.call(this);
        var values = {};
        for(var i = 0, l = properties.length ; i < l ; i++) {
            values[properties[i]] = arguments[i];
        }
        this.set(values);
    };
    module.prototype = Object.create(Backbone.Model.prototype);
    module.prototype.constructor = module;
    _.each(properties, function(property) {
        var propertyCap = property.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + property.slice(1);
        module.prototype["get" + propertyCap] = function() {
            return this.get(property);
        },
        module.prototype["set" + propertyCap] = function(value) {
            var values = {};
            values[property] = value;
            return this.set(values);
        }
    });
    return module;
}
```

Then you define your prototype like this :

```
var MyEntity = generatePrototype(["name", "surname"]);
```

Both solutions in a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sazj8re8/2/